# How do I set the python version in my chef-solo using poise-python

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

How do I set the python version in my chef-solo role?

```
"poise-python":{
        "install_python2": true,
        "install_python3": true
    },
```

the default for python is 3.5 but I want 3.6

when using the below on ubuntu 16.04 I get this error:

```
"poise-python":{
    "install_python2": true,
    "install_python3": true,
    "options":{
        "package_name":"python3.6"
    }
},



Recipe: poise-python::default
  * python_runtime[3] action install
    * poise_languages_system[python3.6] action install

    Running handlers:
[2017-08-01T04:48:41+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2017-08-01T04:48:41+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
    Running handlers complete
[2017-08-01T04:48:41+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2017-08-01T04:48:41+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
    Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 03 seconds
[2017-08-01T04:48:41+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-08-01T04:48:41+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-08-01T04:48:41+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-08-01T04:48:41+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-08-01T04:48:41+00:00] ERROR: Package python3.6 would install nil, which does not match 3. Please set the package_name or package_version provider options.
[2017-08-01T04:48:41+00:00] ERROR: Package python3.6 would install nil, which does not match 3. Please set the package_name or package_version provider options.
[2017-08-01T04:48:41+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
[2017-08-01T04:48:41+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It installs the latest 3.x it knows about for the chosen provider, which would be either distro packages or SCL currently. Probably needs updating to know which OSes have 3.6 available. If you tell me which OS you're on I can tell you how to override it.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 AND 16.04

Comment: 3.6 packages are not available for 14.04, for 16.04 you can override it like this: `options package_name: 'python3.6'`. I'll get things updated for 16.04 when I get a chance.

Comment: Where do I place "options package_name: 'python3.6'"?  I was looking to place in the json object in my role..just for 16.04 is fine

Comment: Are you sure there is a 3.6 package for 16.04? I don't see it in the package system: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3.6

Comment: Looks like Yakkety (16.10) was the first to include 3.6, https://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/python3.6

Comment: Do if I do that..is at least my NEW json format correct based on your suggest of adding options:package_name keys?  Its becuase of the lack of a apt-get 3.6 package is why it failed?  See this for 16.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get